# Is there any apt-get/dpkg/aptitude option to get apt cache folder location?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

`apt` cache folder default location is `/var/cache/apt/archives`.
i work in a python script. is there any way to know cache folder location in `code`. like run a `apt-get` option. like: `apt-get --cache--folder-location`!

Answer (score 1):

try -

```
import apt_pkg
apt_pkg.init()
arch_location = apt_pkg.config.find_file('Dir::cache::archives')
```

http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/index.html

Comment: so nice.
it's seems that's not official python library, but it is already installed in my distro(linux mint).
thx